# Identifying the coordinate system in a set of Australian data

Tags: coordinate-system, datum, australia

I have the following set of data.

| Name | Easting | Northing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Point 1 | 7675 | 0576 |
| Point 2 | 7758 | 0330 |
| Point 3 | 7568 | 0864 |

I would like to know what coordinate system this data uses, to convert it to latitude and longitude later.

I did not find any documentation about the coordinate system used. The data is from an public university document.

I know the locations are somewhere in Zone 50 of WGS84 (West-Western Australia).

I saw on another question that projfinder.com usually helps in these situations, but I am unsure how to use it or analyse the results it returned.

The data can be found here:
https://library.dbca.wa.gov.au/static/FullTextFiles/069766.pdf
See pages 178 - 182.

Any ideas?

After using a map from [here](https://library.dbca.wa.gov.au/static/FullTextFiles/063981.pdf)
and the original data as seen [here](https://library.dbca.wa.gov.au/static/FullTextFiles/069766.pdf) (see pages 178-182), I created this image. Does the image help identify the identify the coordinate system used in the set of data?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried multiplying each value by 1,000 and then plot them in Zone 50 to see their locations?

Comment: You need some more information. Zone 50South WGS84 coordinates in the Australian Continent (EPSG32750) are in the valid range on the Continent SW: 320,300E- 6125, 000N; NW: 181,900E- 7562,000N NE: 816,000E- 7793,000N SE: 785,000E- 6217,000N. No amount of multiplying will solve this- you are missing at least 2 digits in East and 3 in North

Comment: If, for example, you can find which map these points are located on, that might be enough information to infer the missing digits. What are the locations that these data represent?

Comment: can you give a link to the data/document?

Comment: @nmtoken, I have edited the question to include a link to the document, see pages 178-182.

Comment: Perhaps cross reference with https://library.dbca.wa.gov.au/static/FullTextFiles/063981.pdf